# bootstrap-table fixed header not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have used `bootstrap-table` to set a table in my project. Everything works fine except scroll bar inside the `tbody`.

There is no scroll bar there. What am I missing? I believe if the scroll-bar is visible then the `fixed-header` for the table feature should also work fine.

```
<table id="tblMain" class="table table-bordered table-hover" data-show-refresh="false" data-click-to-select="false" data-single-select="true" data-show-toggle="false" data-show-columns="false" data-cache="false" data-page-number="@Model.CommonVariable" data-url='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'  data-side-pagination="server" data-pagination="true" data-search="false" data-query-params="queryParams" data-response-handler="respHandler">
    <thead class="table-head">
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id" data-formatter="SomeFunction">Item ID</th>
            <th data-field="name" data-formatter="SomeFunction2">Item Name</th>
            <th data-field="price" data-formatter="SomeFunction3">Item Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAFX/Mq52k/16/)...

This was not created by me but i think it is what you are looking for.

```
    table {
        table-layout:fixed;
    }

    .div-table-content {
      height:150px;
      overflow-y:auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `data-height` option to active fixed-header feature, for example: http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/.

Comment: `data-height="100vh"` does not seem to work. Is there an option to set `data-height` to a non pixel-unit?